# Creating book type flip side animation using uipageviewcontroller Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, flip

I want to create an interface like the image above . When you turn the page this is the kind of behavior happening.
[image]
  So what is different here is that the cover (the black part) is still visible once you turn the page (the cover is flippable as well, not just a static asset). In a UIViewController when I flip the page it unloads the previous view. So how do I go about implementing this ?Any help or nudge in the right direction will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Have you found any library/solution like this?

Comment: Can you please provide the solution for it..? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this turorial. It helped me a lot!

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

For the page turn effect you need to go in Interface Builder and select page curl for your UIPageViewController.

Comment: Thank you David will let you know